# Flutter UI hangs on async operation

Tags: user-interface, asynchronous, flutter

How to structure the following code correctly? I launch an expensive async operation. The "runExpensiveOperation" method stops the spinning CircularProgressIndicator so it seems it is executed on the main thread. Is there anything like "dispatch_async" like on native iOS?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void _pressed() async {
    print("I am pressed");
    print("I will make a cheap operation now");
    await runExpensiveOperation();
  }

  Future<void> runExpensiveOperation() async  {
    print('starting expensive operation');
    for (var i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {
      List<int> bytes = utf8.encode('somethingtohash');
      String hash = sha256.convert(bytes).toString();
    }
    print('finished expensive operation');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Press me for tough operation"),
              onPressed: _pressed,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use Isolates for that case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void _pressed() async {
    print("I am pressed");
    print("I will make a cheap operation now");

    // string returned is "Good Morning"
    String string = await compute(runExpensiveOperation, null); // this is what you need
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Press me for tough operation"),
              onPressed: _pressed,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// make sure this is outside your class definition 
Future<String> runExpensiveOperation(void _) async  {
  print('starting expensive operation');
  for (var i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {
      List<int> bytes = utf8.encode('somethingtohash');
      String hash = sha256.convert(bytes).toString();
  }
  print('finished expensive operation');
  return "Good Morning";
}
```

Comment: It does work as expected. One question remains: how do I return a result to the Widget? Let us say I want to return a String with "done"?

Comment: First of all I do give an accepted answer mark because it runs well and does what I expect. Secondly I really do not understand why this works. Does "await" within "_pressed" lets the event loop on the main thread to continue operation? Why is the main thread not getting blocked at that await?

Comment: Because this is isolate (separate process), it has its own thread and main thread and this thread doesn't share same memory. They just send messages back and forth, like our isolate is sending back Good Morning message to main thread.

Comment: The `runExpensiveOperation` needed a return type of `Future<String>` for me. Also beware, this threading/isolate stuff doesn't work in the Chrome device - had better luck in the Android emulator.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad how to pass param to the isolate and execute the expensive operation?
And another question is how to listen to the messages that been sent from isolate and show updated response in UI? let's say something like download progress

Comment: Just like @SalarBahador said, really need info on how to do this.

Comment: @SalarBahador to answer the first question, the second parameter of  `compute` is the param that would be passed in to `runExpensiveOperation`. Example code  [here](https://github.com/tadaspetra/flutter_basics/blob/master/019_isolates/lib/main.dart)

Comment: This is an elegant solution.

Comment: don't forget to import `package:flutter/foundation.dart` for `compute`